# ¿Cómo validar fecha DD/MM/AAAA numero de identificación y un entero de un Excel después de subirlo en C# y antes de insertar los campos en SQL?

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel

Intento seleccionar la columna para validar que este en formato correcto

`if (dt_PG.Columns[1].ColumnMapping == DateT )`,

Las columnas de fecha son la `1` y `2`, las de numero de identificación es  la 0 y la de el numero entero es la `4`

```
protected void btn_guardar_Archivo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt_PG;

        if (FUpL_Arch.HasFile)
        {
            string FileName = Path.GetFileName(FUpL_Arch.PostedFile.FileName);
            string path = string.Concat((Server.MapPath("~/Archivos/DOCUMENTOS_ADJUNTOS/PRUEBAS/" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy") + "_User_ " + IdUsuario + "_" + FUpL_Arch.FileName)));
            FUpL_Arch.PostedFile.SaveAs(path);

            dt_PG = ExcelToDataTable(path, true);

            string[] Colum = { "Numero Identificacion", "Fecha Inicio", "Fecha Fin", "Id Turno" };


            if (dt_PG.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                if (dt_PG.Columns.Count == Colum.Length)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dt_PG.Rows)
                    {
                        try
                        {

                            BIO_Programacion_Detalle_BRL.InsertOrUpdate(new BIO_Programacion_Detalle()
                            {
                                Id_Programacion = txt_BPG.Text.ToInt32(),
                                Id_IE = dr[0].ToInt32(),
                                FechaInicio = dr[1].ToString(),
                                FechaFin = dr[2].ToString(),
                                Id_Turno = dr[3].ToInt32(),
                                Estado = 1,
                                UsuarioCreacion = IdUsuario
                            }, 1);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            MostrarAlerta("Error: " + ex.Message);
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MostrarAlerta("Archivo cargado incorrecto verificar cantidad de columnas");
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MostrarAlerta("Seleccione un archivo");
        }
    }
    public static DataTable ExcelToDataTable(string filePath, bool hasHeaders)
    {
        DataTable dtexcel = new DataTable();
        string HDR = hasHeaders ? "Yes" : "No";
        string strConn;
        if (filePath.Substring(filePath.LastIndexOf('.')).ToLower() == ".xlsx")
            strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=" + HDR + ";IMEX=0\"";
        else
            strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=" + HDR + ";IMEX=0\"";
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strConn);
        conn.Open();
        DataTable schemaTable = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
        DataRow schemaRow = schemaTable.Rows[0];
        string sheet = schemaRow["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
        if (!sheet.EndsWith("_"))
        {
            string query = "SELECT  * FROM [" + sheet + "]";
            OleDbDataAdapter daexcel = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn);
            dtexcel.Locale = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
            daexcel.Fill(dtexcel);
        }

        conn.Close();
        return dtexcel;
    }
```

Comment: Y cual seria el problema que estas teniendo?

Comment: ya valide que la cantidad de columnas sea correcta, pero necesito validar que el formato de las fechas sea correcto antes de insertar en la BD

Comment: Donde esta explicado todo eso en la pregunta? por favor, agrega toda la informacion necesaria a la pregunta. En que formato tiene que ir una fecha en tu base de datos? que intentaste para validar la fecha? que columnas se deben validar? como se deben validar? que error te dio al tratar de validar la fecha como tal?

Comment: las fechas van en la columna 1 y 2 , la identificacion en 0 y el entero en 4

Comment: Por favor, que el titulo sea claro, y agrega todas las descripciones de los problemas en la pregunta. y agrega que fue lo que intentaste que no funciono

Comment: he tratado también de validar de esta forma pero ahora todos me los marca como error así estén bien

Comment: que es DateT? las validaciones de las cosas se hacen comprobando que efectivamente los datos son transformables a ese tipo.

Answer (score 0):

Para validar podes usar el método `TryParse()` de [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx) o [DateTimeOffset](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2) dependiendo como prefieras manejar las fechas

Te dejo un ejemplo para que lo apliques en tu problema.

```
string fechaAValidar = "";
DateTime fecha;

if(DateTime.TryParse(fechaAValidar, out fecha))
{
   //La fecha es válida y está almacenada en la variable fecha
}
else
{
   //La fecha es invalida
}
```